# Firebase push notification is not received android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit

i'm trying to send notification from android using retrofit and i followed the offical documentation from firebase.
i setup retrofit with https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and when i post notifications retrofit returns response but the message dosen't appear in my logs. i think my service is not working after the message was posted.

MainActivity

```
const val TOPIC = "MyTopic"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(TOPIC)


        val btnSend = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSend)

        btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseNotificationData(
                NotificationData("Notification title", "Notification message"),
                TOPIC
            ).also {
                postNotification(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun postNotification(notification: FirebaseNotificationData) =
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = RetrofitInstance.api.postNotification(notification)

            if (response.isSuccessful)
                Log.d("Retrofit", "Message was posted")
            else
                Log.e("Retrofit", response.errorBody().toString())
        }
}
```

Service

```
class FirebaseNotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)

        Log.d("onMessageReceived","message received")
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.firebasenotification">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.FirebaseNotification">
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <service android:name=".FirebaseNotificationService"
           android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
               <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </service>

   </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

> onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the
> following exceptions:
>
> Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In
> this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray.
> A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the
> background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
> device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
> of the intent of your launcher Activity.

While testing, make sure the app is in background, when you send FCM notifications.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive